# Rails Query to return users belongs to any cities & not belong to any cities

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, postgresql-9.1, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have `Many to Many Associations` between two tables: For Ex users & cities

```
users
id  name
1   Bob
2   Jon
3   Tom
4   Gary
5   Hary

cities
id     name 
1      London
2      New-york
3      Delhi

users_cities
id   user_id   city_id
1    1         2
2    2         1
3    3         1
4    3         2
5    4         3
```

I want two sql queries

**Query which accepts array of city_id and return all the users belongs to that cities.**
For Ex when city_id : [1, 2] then result should be 
O/P should be

```
   id  name
    1   Bob
    2   Jon
    3   Tom
```

**Query which accepts array of city_id and return all the users who do not belong to those cities.**
For Ex when city_id : [1, 2] then result should be 
O/P should be

```
    id  name
    4   Gary
    5   Hary
```

Note:- i am using

`user.rb`

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :cities
```

`city.rb`

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need two methods/scopes

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :cities

  scope :by_cities, ->(city_ids) {includes(:cities).where(cities: {id: city_ids}).distinct}

  # There are several ways to do that
  # 1. That will return all not associated records but that we won't need
  # In this scenario, You need OR condition like city_ids OR NULL 
  # This will return => ["Hary"] 
  scope :not_by_cities, -> {includes(:cities).where(cities: {id: nil})}

  # 2. Need to create a scope in City model
  # scope :city_ids, -> all.pluck(:id) 
  # This will return => ["Gary", "Hary"] 
  scope :not_by_cities, -> {includes(:cities).where(cities: {id: [City.city_ids - city_ids, nil]})}

  # 3. If you are on Rails 5, It is much more easier
  # This will return => ["Gary", "Hary"] 
  scope :not_by_cities, -> {includes(:cities).where.not(cities: {id: city_ids}).where(cities: {id: nil})} 
end
```

## For Option 2

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :cities
    scope :city_ids, -> {all.pluck(:id)}
 end
```

Result:

```
>> User.by_cities([1,2]).pluck(:name)
=> ["Bob", "Jon", "Tom"]

>> User.not_by_cities.pluck(:name)
=> ["Gary", "Hary"]
```

If You are Rails 4.x and still want some easy solution. Use anyone of there

- [Squeel](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel)
- [ActiverecordAnyOf](https://github.com/oelmekki/activerecord_any_of)
- [SmartTuple](https://github.com/dadooda/smart_tuple)
- [Arel](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/arel/Arel).

Hope this will help you.